# How to configure the header pane in a custom Hello World View created in SugarCRM 7

Tags: sugarcrm, sugarbean

I have create a custom view from scratch in SugarCRM PRO 7.6 displaying only the text "Hello World" and placed that view inside a custom layout created to display that view.

With the modifications i have made i have suucceded in displaying the "Hello World" view inside my newly created layout but i am not succeded in displaying anything in the header pane available right over my custom view.

The folder structure of my layout and view is shown below:

[image]

All the four files along with their containg code are shown below:

**helloworldlayout.js**

```
({})
```

**helloworldlayout.php**

```
<?php
$viewdefs['Accounts']['base']['layout']['helloworldlayout'] = array(
    'components' => array(
        array(
            'layout' => array(
                'components' => array(
                    array(
                        'layout' => array(
                            'components' => array(
                                array(
                                    'view' => 'helloworldview',
                                    'primary' => true,
                                ),
                            ),
                            'type' => 'simple',
                            'name' => 'main-pane',
                            'span' => 8,
                        ),
                    ),
                    array(
                        'layout' => array(
                            'components' => array(
                                array(
                                    'layout' => 'sidebar',
                                ),
                            ),
                            'type' => 'simple',
                            'name' => 'side-pane',
                            'span' => 4,
                        ),
                    ),
                    array(
                        'layout' => array(
                            'components' => array(
                                array(
                                    'layout' => array(
                                        'type' => 'dashboard',
                                        'last_state' => array(
                                            'id' => 'last-visit',
                                        )
                                    ),
                                    'context' => array(
                                        'forceNew' => true,
                                        'module' => 'Home',
                                    ),
                                ),
                            ),
                            'type' => 'simple',
                            'name' => 'dashboard-pane',
                            'span' => 4,
                        ),
                    ),
                    array(
                        'layout' => array(
                            'components' => array(
                                array(
                                    'layout' => 'preview',
                                ),
                            ),
                            'type' => 'simple',
                            'name' => 'preview-pane',
                            'span' => 8,
                        ),
                    ),
                ),
                'type' => 'default',
                'name' => 'sidebar',
                'span' => 12,
            ),
        ),
    ),
    'type' => 'record',
    'name' => 'base',
    'span' => 12,
);
```

**helloworldview.js**

```
({})
```

**helloworldview.hbs**

```
<h1>Hello World</h1>
```

Finally I am accessing this Hello World view using:

```
<my_sugar_instance>/#Accounts/layout/helloworldlayout
```

Can any body guide me what are the best practices to configure the header pane highlighted in the image shown below:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at the following solution suggested by Tevfik Tümer
https://community.sugarcrm.com/thread/27826

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that  'view' => 'helloworldview' is too nested within helloworldlayout.php. For example, if you use the following code as your helloworldlayout.php:

```
 <?php 
  $viewdefs['Accounts']['base']['layout']['helloworldlayout'] = array(
  'components' => array(
     array(
        'view' => 'helloworldview',
     ),
    ),
   'type' => 'simple',
   'name' => 'base',
   'span' => 12,
   );
```

Then you will observe that there's no space:

[helloworld without spaces](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u8jZz.png)

Comment: Ye i understand but i really want it in the structure i have shown in my question. Any way thanks for the help.

Comment: I'd recommend process of elinimation in cases like this, although it looks like you found an answer